# Share an ATI Catalyst Profile across several/all users

Tags: profile, amd-catalyst

We've set up some hotkeys in the ATI Catalyst Control Panel on a communal machine, and we're trying to share this among a number of users, possibly all users.

The profile is stored as `MyProfile.xml` in the Local Settings tree; the profile can be loaded through a shortcut, but unfortunately the Profilename switch simply expects the name of the profile rather than the path to the XML file.

And while we can copy the profile to appropriate folders under other users accounts, the mere presence of the XML isn't enough to make the profile available to the user. A quick scan of the registry didn't reveal much, though I suspect there is something in there to be aware of.

Any ideas on how we can share this profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATI *eventually* got back to me - I need to add the profilename to the followings key:

```
My Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ATI\ACE\Settings\Runtime\Graphics\ProfileOptions
```

Comment: Can you explain how what "Profile switch" you used to load the profile?

Comment: @tobsen - sorry, it was 3 years ago; I'm not even with the same company anymore.